# Using a MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a social network in which you can follow someone or be friends with them. The data you are able to see depends on the type of relationship you have with a user. Right now I have two tables to work with. Posts and Relationships.

Posts:

```
| user_id | post_id | story |
-----------------------------
|  1      |  1      | text. |
-----------------------------
```

Relationships:

```
| rel_id  | user_1  | user_2| status |
--------------------------------------
|  1      |  1      |   2   |    3   |
--------------------------------------
```

I also have a users table but I don't think that is important here. SO, basically I want to select all of the posts from users that I am friends with or following. User_2 is always the recipient of the relationship. The numbers 1, 2 and 3 represent the "status" of the relationship. 1 being you are following the recipient, 3 being you are friends, and 4 being you are following the recipient (the only difference is that you also have a pending friend request). I set up a SELECT QUERY but it is not working right.

```
$query=" SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN relationships ON (posts.user_id=    
relationships.user_2 AND relationships.user_1 = $user_id AND relationships.status = 4 
OR 3 OR 1)";
```

It selects all the posts ever, twice. Why is that? I want it to only select the posts where the user posting the post is in a relationship with me, with a status of 1, 3, or 4. What might I be doing wrong? What are other ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

That's not how `OR` works. Perhaps you should try `IN`.

```
... relationships.status IN (4, 3, 1) ...
```

As for the duplication, use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: When he fixes the OR, I think the duplication will go away, so he doesn't need DISTINCT. He's getting duplicates because "OR 3 OR 1" is making it match all rows, since these are always true.

Comment: @Barmar: Duplication of records usually comes from the relations rather than any fixed comparisons.

Comment: Good point. I think it could only happen if the same pair of users appears multiple times in the relationships table, with different status. In that case, DISTINCT is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OR` in the `WHERE` clause condition is not in the correct syntax. try something like this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    posts a 
            LEFT JOIN relationships b
                ON a.user_id = b.user_2 
WHERE   b.user_1 = $user_id AND 
        b.status IN (1,3,4)
```

I suggest that you use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** extensions.

In PDO, it could look like this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT   * 
                      FROM  posts a 
                           LEFT JOIN relationships b
                                ON a.user_id = b.user_2 
                     WHERE  b.user_1 = ? AND 
                            b.status IN (1,3,4)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $user_id);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Remember to always filter your inputs especially it is used querying your database.